# Export customers from a Mondo shop to Magento?

Tags: customer, import, export

Is there a way to import Mondo customer data including passwords into Magento? I seachred the net for a while but came up with nothing.

Comment: How is your data formatted? CSV file? SQL?

Comment: It will be CSV or XML

Answer (score 2):

You can import hashed passwords into Magento with ImportExport. Go to `System > Import/Export > Export` and export some sample customer data to see what the file should look like. It will include a field with a password hash. The import accepts the same format. You cannot import clear text passwords, you have to hash them before import. As far as I know, you can use a simple md5 hash.